# Distance calculation implementation

Tags: c++

What I'm asking for is the review of a particular implementation of the haversine formula, found under:
http://blog.julien.cayzac.name/2008/10/arc-and-distance-between-two-points-on.html
This site is linked under the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Problem: I get the wrong distance for the points:

```
lat/lon, lat2/lon2

36.987814/-122.107887,   38.989185/-122.116728
```

I get a distance of 4336622.8812906 (meters)
however according to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html it should be about 222.5 km.

If somebody could point out the error in this implementation, that would be great:

```
inline double getDist(double *gp) {
    /// @brief The usual PI/180 constant
    static const double DEG_TO_RAD = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;
    /// @brief Earth's quatratic mean radius for WGS-84
    static const double EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 6372797.560856;

    double latitudeArc  = (gp[0] - gp[2]) * DEG_TO_RAD;
    double longitudeArc = (gp[1] - gp[3]) * DEG_TO_RAD;
    double latitudeH = sin(latitudeArc * 0.5);
    latitudeH *= latitudeH;
    double lontitudeH = sin(longitudeArc * 0.5);
    lontitudeH *= lontitudeH;
    double tmp = cos(gp[0]*DEG_TO_RAD) * cos(gp[2]*DEG_TO_RAD);
    return EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS*2.0 * asin(sqrt(latitudeH + tmp*lontitudeH));
}
```

Comment: This is also a good time to point out that your code should compile and run and generate the results you claim. It was a good guess by @acraig but you definitely made the situation harder to solve by not providing compilable working code. Also this is the wrong forum for code that does not work you should have asked this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your implementation. There must therefore be something wrong with how you're declaring or populating `gp`.
Doing it like this:

```
double gp[4] = {36.987814, -122.107887, 38.989185, -122.116728};
printf("%.6f\n", getDist(gp));
```

gives the expected answer of `222606.439993`

Comment: thanks a lot for the verification. the problem was further up in the code, with the initialization of gp[0]

Comment: Prefer to use `double gp[] = {/*STUFF*/};` By explicitly leaving the `[]` empty you are asking the compiler to calculate the size of the array based on the initialize. Doing it this way prevents initial counting errors and problems when the array size changes during maintenance.